# Javascript Regex setting opposite rules

Tags: javascript, regex

in a nut shell i need two regular expressions to detect either .css or .scss files.

I need to return true if the following criteria is met:

**#1**

- File name can be anything but must not equal 'global'
- File extensions must be either '.css' or '.scss'

**#2**

- File name must equal 'global'
- File extensions must be either '.css' or '.scss'

Comment: May you show us what you have already tried?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Regex A:

```
^global\.s?css$
```

Regex B:

```
\.s?css$
```

Your use case #2 is true when Regex A matches. Your use case #1 is true when Regex A does not match, and Regex B matches.

In particular: `^` means "start of the string", which guarantees the first six characters in the matching string are `global`. `\.` means "match a period". Without the `\`, `.` on its own means "match any character", which we don't want. `s?` means "match either nothing or an `s`". `$` means "end of the string", which guarantees the last three characters in the matching string are `css`.

Comment: This is great, however i need to explicitly state that 'global' is not allowed in the regex b. Is this possible using `?!`

Comment: Yes, you can use `^(!?global\.s?css$).*\.s?css$`.

Comment: Wow thanks! should that be `^(?!global\.s?css$).*\.s?css$`

Comment: Yes, sorry!  Good catch. :)

Comment: Star thanks a lot! I can see these are correctly returning true/false - however they don't seem to work in webpacks 'test' property. I'll keep digging, but if anyone has any suggestions That would be great!